# Google Maps javascript api v3 does not show map

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm here today because i have a problem with Google Maps javascript api version 3. My problem is that Google maps does not appear.. But how you can see in this screen, in the code there is the map:

[image]

I have insert my code into jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/05ktc2a6/) but does not work. I have just tryed use div with width and height 100% but not work.

If you prefer i put the code:

```
<body>

<div style="height:100%; width:100%;position:absolute;">
<div id="map"></div>
</div>
<script>
 var map;

function initMap() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: 44.769503083884,
            lng: 10.431460571289
        },
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 15,
        disableDefaultUI: true
    });
}
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCKKcVR26NAZ7j0zUtTY3Stu-DmcUhMW1E&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
```

Could anyone help me? Some weeks agò it was working, i don't know what is appened :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use 100% height on an element, but the document and document body have no specified height, it isn't possible for the browser to calculate the height...

You can solve this using the newer `vh` measure rather than a percentage, or by setting the height of `html, body` to 100%.

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    border: 1px solid Aqua;
}
```

See an [example on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hd2s2qL/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same problem I had after the October 11 update, but my maps did not show either.

I had to fix 2 things:
 `< meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` (I used EmulateIE8, but had to change it to edge. I read somewhere that googlemaps does not support IE9 anymore, so that may be the reason).

This fixed my problem in a new window, but my map in an iframe still showed up as white.

I had to add "v=3" (without quotes) to the googleapi.com call, so I am using this line now:

`< SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3">`

Now my maps work again in IE(11), Firefox and Chrome (i did not test other browsers).

Hopefully this helps you too.